# Coroutining in Prolog: when argument is a list (it has fixed length)

Tags: prolog, logical-purity, prolog-coroutining

**Question**

Is it possible to schedule a goal to be executed as soon as the length of a list is known / fixed or, as @false pointed out in the comments, a given argument becomes a [proper] list? Something along this line:

```
when(fixed_length(L), ... some goal ...).
```

When-conditions can be constructed using `?=/2`, `nonvar/1`, `ground/1`, `,/2`, and `;/2` only and it seems they are not very useful when looking at the whole list.

As a further detail, I'm looking for a solution that presents [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) if that is possible.

**Motivation**

I think this condition might be useful when one wants to use a predicate `p(L)` to check a property for a list `L`, but without using it in a generative way.

E.g. it might be the case that [for efficiency or termination reasons] one prefers to execute the following conjunction `p1(L), p2(L)` in this order if `L` has a fixed length (i.e. `L` is a list), and in reversed order `p2(L), p1(L)` otherwise (if `L` is a partial list).

This might be achieved like this:

```
when(fixed_length(L), p1(L)), p2(L).
```

**Update**

I did implement a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025403/1478624), but it lacks purity.

Comment: Just a terminological issue. A list is `[]`, `[_]`, `[_,_]`. But `[_,_|_]` is **not** a list, it is a *partial list*. For this `when(list(L), G)` might be a better name.

Comment: Is there a name that comprises both lists and partial lists? I thought all partial lists are also lists.

Comment: You can say of type list. Pre-ISO terminology was also: proper list (for a list and not a partial list) and improper list for, say `[1|2]`. But if only proper lists are the real ones, this would somewhat imply that proper is needed also for other terms, like, integers.

Comment: Please note that `Xs` is a partial list, too. Thus, any term is a partial list that is not a list itself but that possesses  instances that are lists.

Comment: I will edit my question and answer with the correct terminology soon. I understand now that my question is actually about partial lists becoming lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if `when/2` would support a condition `list/1`. In the meantime, consider:

```
list_ltruth(L, Bool) :-
   freeze(L, nvlist_ltruth(L, Bool)).

nvlist_ltruth(Xs0, Bool) :-
   (  Xs0 == [] -> Bool = true
   ;  Xs0 = [_|Xs1] -> freeze(Xs1, nvist_ltruth(Xs1, Bool))
   ;  Bool = false
   ).

when_list(L, Goal_0) :-
   nvlist_ltruth(L, Bool),
   when(nonvar(Bool),( Bool == true, Goal_0 )).
```

So you can combine this also with other conditions.

Maybe produce a type error, if `L` is not a list.

```
   when(nonvar(Bool), ( Bool == true -> Goal_0 ; sort([], L) ).
```

Above trick will only work in an ISO conforming Prolog system like SICStus or GNU that produces a `type_error(list,[a|nonlist])` for `sort([],[a|nonlist])`, otherwise replace it by:

```
   when(nonvar(Bool),
      ( Bool == true -> Goal_0 ; throw(error(type_error(list,L), _)).
```

Many systems contain some implementation specific built-in like `'$skip_list'` to traverse lists rapidly, you might want to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to answer my own question, but not with a pure solution.

**Some observations**

The difficulty encountered in writing a program that schedules some goal for execution when the length of a list is precisely known is the fact that the actual condition might change. Consider this:

```
when(fixed_length(L), Goal)
```

The length of the list might change if `L` is unbound or if the *last tail* is unbound. Say we have this argument `L = [_,_|Tail]`. `L` has a fixed width only if `Tail` has a fixed width (in other words, `L` is a list if `T` is a list). So, a condition that checks `Tail` might be the only thing to do at first. But if `Tail` becomes `[a|Tail2]` a new when-condition that tests if `Tail2` is a list is needed.

### The solution

**1. Getting the when-condition**

I've implemented a predicate that relates a partial list with the when-condition that signals when it might become a list (i.e. `nonvar(T)` where `T` is the *deepest tail*).

```
condition_fixed_length(List, Cond):-
    \+ (List = []),
    \+ \+ (List = [_|_]),
    List = [_|Tail],
    condition_fixed_length(Tail, Cond).
condition_fixed_length(List, Cond):-
    \+ \+ (List = []),
    \+ \+ (List = [_|_]),
    Cond = nonvar(List).
```

**2. Recursively when-conditioning**

```
check_on_fixed_length(List, Goal):-
    (
         condition_fixed_length(List, Condition)
     ->
         when(Condition, check_on_fixed_length(List, Goal))
     ;
         call(Goal)
    ).
```

### Example queries

Suppose we want to check that all elements of `L` are `a` when the size of `L` is fixed:

```
?- check_on_fixed_length(L, maplist(=(a), L)).
when(nonvar(L), check_on_fixed_length(L, maplist(=(a), L))).
```

... and then `L = [_,_|Tail]`:

```
?- check_on_fixed_length(L, maplist(=(a), L)), L = [_,_|L1].
L = [_G2887, _G2890|L1],
when(nonvar(L1), check_on_fixed_length([_G2887, _G2890|L1], maplist(=(a), [_G2887, _G2890|L1]))).

?- check_on_fixed_length(L, maplist(=(a), L)), L = [_,_|L1], length(L1, 3).
L = [a, a, a, a, a],
L1 = [a, a, a].
```

## Impurity

`conditon_fixed_length/2` is the source of impurity as it can be seen from the following query:

```
?- L = [X, Y|Tail], condition_fixed_length(L, Cond), L = [a,a].
L = [a, a],
X = Y, Y = a,
Tail = [],
Cond = nonvar([]).

?- L = [X, Y|Tail], L = [a, a], condition_fixed_length(L, Cond).
false.
```